# Ajax call always return success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call to my controller, which in turn calls a service which returns true or false. I cannot seem to figure out why this always triggers my success function when it returns from controller to view.

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult TagUnit(int id, string selectedItem)
{
    try
    {
        var result = UnitClient.TagUnit(id, selectedItem);
        if (!result)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        return Json(new {success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Json(new {success = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Cshtml - Javascript - Ajax**

```
 .on("select2-selecting", function (e) {
            var url = '@Url.Content("~/UnitDetails/TagUnit/" + Model.ViewUnitContract.Id)';
            var id = e.val;
            var tagName = e.object.text;
            console.log(id + " : " + tagName);

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: { selectedItem: tagName },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function () {
                    alert('Success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error');
                }
            });
        }).select2('val', ['1', '2']);
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should validate server result data in success method.

```
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: { selectedItem: tagName },
     type: 'GET',
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
        if (data != null && data.success) {
            alert('Success');
        } else {
            alert('Error');
        }
     },
     error: function () {
        alert('Error');
     }
 });
```

Error method calls if on the server occurred 500 error or server is not avaliable, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander! Worked like a charm! Guess I could just return a `JsonBehaviour.DenyGet` in order to provoke the error aswell?

Comment: Yes, you can, but the best solution will be return success = true/false. If you will use JsonBehaviour.DenyGet you can't inform client about problem reason. In the case success - you can.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you throw an exception, it will still return with a success status code. So what I have done is create an ajax call error handler attribute that can be attached to your MVC methods. It will capture uncaught exceptions, set an error status code and give a generic error message (and also log to Elmah). The attribute is below

```
public class HandleJsonErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        var serviceException = filterContext.Exception as Exception;

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                errorMessage = "Generic error message", 
                errorType = 0

            },
            JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };

        var kayttaja = (Kayttaja.TKayttajantiedot)filterContext.HttpContext.Session["userKayttajanTiedot"];
        Global.HandleApplicationError(serviceException, kayttaja);

        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        // Log to elmah
        //Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(filterContext.Exception);
    }
}
```

Then decorate your action methods that should only be called by Ajax with: `[Campus.Attribuutit.HandleJsonError]`

The important line for triggering the error handler in the ajax call object is `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I understand your question properly.

**success** function in Ajax will execute if the request is successful. And **error** function will execute if the request fails. You have to check what the server returns inside of the success function.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/