# Ajax Return Issue in Asp. Net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website with asp.net mvc 4,

I have a method that checks user whether registered or not. I use ajax for it, if user already registered, I would like to write a message on a div on registration webpage, if not, I would like to register user and return home page. I hope its clear. because it seems a bit difficult to understand.

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#form0').submit(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault(); 
        var result = "";
        var form = $(this);


        $.ajax({
            url: "CheckUser", //form.attr("action"),
            data: form.serialize(),
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#ajax-loader").show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $("#ajax-loader").hide();
            },
            error: function(request, status, error) {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText);
                if (request.status == 403) // authorize error
                {
                    myRouting(obj.LogOnUrl, "403 error", "error");

                } else {

                  alert("Error Occured: " + error.responseText + "\nError Code: " +
     request.responseText + " -- " + request.responseText);
                    var msg = "Error: " + error + "\nErrorCode: " + request.status;
                    myRouting("", msg, "error");

                }
            },

            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data, function() {
                    result += this.Name + "\n";
                });


                myRouting("", data, "data");

            }
        });

         return false;
    });



$(function myRouting(site, message, type) {


    if (type == "error") {
        $('#searchFailed').remove();
        $('<div id="searchFailed"></div>').appendTo('#searchMain');
        $('#searchFailed').append("<p>" + message + "</p>");
    } 
    });


});
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm("CheckUser", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form0" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Registration Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>                 



            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
            </li>                       


            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m =>m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>

            <li>
                @Html.Label("Confirm Password")
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>

            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
            </li>                             


        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

And here is my accountcontroller

```
   [HttpPost]
   [AllowAnonymous]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Register(User model)
   {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {

              var result =   helper.RegisterUser(model);

              if (result)
              return  RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //Json(Url.Action("Index", "Home"));   

            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult CheckUser(User model)
    {
        bool result = helper.IsUserExist(model);

            if (result)
            {
             ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(MembershipCreateStatus.DuplicateUserName));

             return Content("User is already created !!!!");

           }
           return Register(model);
    }
```

I know that in ajax, its not possible to redirect action, but if i could do it "error" in ajax, i can redirect it in ajax..

return content is always being "success" in ajax, even user is not registered before, it stils being "success"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse `success` event with the success of the logic part/authorization of your code.

Success in ajax means the request went through .. you'll need to check the data it returned to see if it has the information for you to determine if it succeeded in checking for the user or not.

Inside the `success` event handler, check the returned data.

If i were you, i wouldn't return a view .. i'd probably return JSON which would clearly have info on the success or failure of the task .. and possibly a description of the error.

Comment: thank you for your reply, you mean like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19722873/ajax-call-always-return-success

Comment: @unbalanced yeah pretty much the idea.